Yield depth on a depth-first non-recursive tree walker?
I'm trying to find a non-recursive "powerful/versatile" tree walker algorithm, ultimately yielding not just the node but the depth of the node, its parent and its sibling index, and able to use a breadth-first search (BFS) or depth-first search (DFS).
It is possible to combine depth-first and bread-first like this, just yielding the node (NB assumes a node which may or may not have the key CHILD_NODES). Example using Python - "Python" tag added but obviously not specific:
def get_walker(walk_by_depth=True):
    def walk(root):
        queue = [root]
        while len(queue) > 0:
            # the first item in the queue
            node_to_yield = queue.pop(0)

            yield node_to_yield

            if CHILD_NODES in node_to_yield:
                depth += 1    
                new_nodes = node_to_yield[CHILD_NODES]
                if walk_by_depth:
                    queue = new_nodes + queue
                else:
                    queue.extend(new_nodes)
    return walk

... and adding a small amount of code lets you yield a depth for a breadth-first search only:
def get_walker(walk_by_depth=True):
    def walk(root):
        queue = [root]
        depth = 0 
        depth_map_of_remaining_items = {0: 1}
        while len(queue) > 0:
            node_to_yield = queue.pop(0)
            if depth_map_of_remaining_items[depth] == 0:
                depth += 1
            depth_map_of_remaining_items[depth] -= 1

            yield node_to_yield, depth

            if CHILD_NODES in node_to_yield:
                depth += 1    
                new_nodes = node_to_yield[CHILD_NODES]
                if walk_by_depth:
                    queue = new_nodes + queue
                else:
                    queue.extend(new_nodes)
                    if depth not in depth_map_of_remaining_items:
                        depth_map_of_remaining_items[depth] = 0
                    depth_map_of_remaining_items[depth] += len(new_nodes)    
                depth -= 1
    return walk

The above code doesn't in fact work with walk_by_depth=True: it doesn't raise an Exception, it just gets the depth wrong. Instinctively I've got a feeling that the code probably just needs a minimal tweak to yield (correct) depth on a DFS, but I've had no success so far.
The thing is, if I can find a way of yielding the depth with a DFS, I believe it will be a fairly easy step to yield, for both BFS and DFS, the parent node, by maintaining a "depth-to-last-node" map. If you can get the parent you can also get the sibling index, at the simplest by using list's index method (though there may be far cleverer ways to get both the parent and the sibling index...).

The idea is to place the depth in the queue too: put pairs of nodes with their depths in the queue, and it will be easy.
Without changing more than necessary in your code to make it work, we get this:
def get_walker(walk_by_depth=True):
    def walk(root):
        queue = [(root, 0)]  # pair the root with its depth
        while len(queue) > 0:
            # the first item in the queue
            node_to_yield, depth = queue.pop(0)  # pop the pair

            yield node_to_yield, depth

            if CHILD_NODES in node_to_yield:
                # create pairs for all child nodes
                new_nodes = [(child, depth+1) for child in node_to_yield[CHILD_NODES]]
                if walk_by_depth:
                    queue = new_nodes + queue
                else:
                    queue.extend(new_nodes)
    return walk

Note that pop(0) and new_nodes + queue are not efficient operations. Consider using a deque.

Thanks... and thanks for the deque tip too. I had in fact considered something along these lines but continue to suspect there's a more elegant solution (similar to my solution for BFS) not involving a list comprehension, which I suggest can't be ideally efficient. I mean nothing's perfect, and I'd be interested in your reaction to that suggestion.

The list comprehension is not essential. I mean you can also write that loop explicitly as a standard for-loop. Efficiency in terms of time complexity is not impacted, although it of course incurs a certain overhead to pair each node with a depth, and put each of these items in a queue.

You mean iterate through all the new nodes which are to be added? Yes, sorry, when I say "more elegant", I mean more elegant than any solution involving such iterations. Maybe there is no alternative, of course!

OK, but understand that under the hood there are already these iterations. Even new_nodes + queue involves an iteration over every element in both lists.

True, of course. But in that case isn't your solution doing TWO iterations? One to make the list of tuples, the other to add that list? Your deque solution probably mitigates that (I have to look into it).

Yes, but two iterations doesn't change the time complexity. You can surely combine those two into one with the use of a deque.

Also have to say your solution is very elegant in terms of the way it provides the opportunity to pass on depth to the next generation. I should probably also throw in the parent and sibling index into that tuple, hmmm...

Implementation using deque as suggested by trincot, yielding node, depth, parent and sibling index:
def get_walker(walk_by_depth=True):
    def walk(root):
        queue = deque([(root, 0, None, 0)]) 
        while len(queue) > 0:
            node_to_yield, depth, parent, sib_index = queue.popleft()  
            yield node_to_yield, depth, parent, sib_index
            if CHILD_NODES in node_to_yield:
                for sib_index, child in enumerate(node_to_yield[CHILD_NODES]):
                    node_tuple = (child, depth+1, node_to_yield, sib_index)
                    if walk_by_depth:
                        queue.insert(sib_index, node_tuple)
                    else:
                        queue.append(node_tuple)
    return walk

variant walker
and, for completeness: I later found I had to implement a sort of variant of a DFS, essentially a DFS but where all children are yielded consecutively. The use case was a test where a database table contains records for each node, and the typical SQL command used to return records for a parent is something like SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE parent_id = ? (and you then go on to examine each child record recursively or quasi-recursively).
So I wanted my test's mock/patch database function to simulate this form of node traversal, and so this universal walker function becomes:
def get_walker(walk_by_depth=True, yield_all_children_together=False):
    def walk(root):
        queue = deque([(root, 0, None, 0)]) 
        while len(queue) > 0:
            node_to_yield, depth, parent, sib_index = queue.popleft()  
            if (not yield_all_children_together) or node_to_yield == root: # NB yield root at start
                yield node_to_yield, depth, parent, sib_index
            if CHILD_NODES in node_to_yield:
                for child_sib_index, child in enumerate(node_to_yield[CHILD_NODES]):
                    node_tuple = (child, depth+1, node_to_yield, child_sib_index)
                    if walk_by_depth:
                        queue.insert(child_sib_index, node_tuple)
                    else:
                        queue.append(node_tuple)
                    if yield_all_children_together:
                        yield child, depth+1, node_to_yield, child_sib_index
    return walk

The call I'm using in this "side effect" in this mock/patch of the database function is then:
variant_dfs_walker = get_walker(True, True)
for node, depth, parent, sib_index in variant_dfs_walker.walk(my_tree):
    ...

... incidentally, running get_walker(False, True) results in an odd variant traversal, slightly different to True, True: not sure whether it ever makes sense. Possibly there should be just 1 parameter, with 3 choices.
I looked around to see whether such a traversal type has a known name but found nothing. If anyone knows...
